# Property not in use

Tags: neo4j

I've been frequently getting the error :

> Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed
>   Property[4104469,used=false,prev=0,next=0] not in use

This happened after an unsuccessful CSV load for some properties, the properties I'm querying exist and I can see their values but if I try to include their vales in any query I get the above error

Can someone help what does this error mean?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your database? That will probably fix it.

Comment: No it didn't fix it and I had to reload the whole graph again to get rid of this error